# NServicebus 4.7.6 is not respecting the SecondLevelRetriesConfig Values on app.config

Tags: c#, nservicebus, nservicebus4

There is no custom configuration in code.

```
<SecondLevelRetriesConfig Enabled="true" TimeIncrease="00:05:00" NumberOfRetries="10" />
```

It works based on the default SecondLevelRetriesConfig values not picking up the custom configuration.

Update:

Sorry for not updating the scenario.
This Scenario happens when nservicebus worker is having configuration for MasternodeConfig. It does not respect worker node config for second level retries. The timeouts are handled in MasterNode (Distributor).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior of SLR is different between major versions of NServiceBus. Below if a dump of the documentation from http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/scalability-and-ha/distributor/error-handling

Please check that link if not using NServiceBus v3, v4 or v5

#### NServiceBus v5.x

The SLR policy *NumberOfRetries* setting its is applied on *both* the distributor and workers, and the *TimeIncrease* setting is applied on the distributor.

When an error occurs the SLR policy is invoked immediately by the fault manager. The message will not be forwarded to the retries queue which is was the previous behavior.

When the retry limit is reached the message is  forwarded immediately to the error queue or else forwarded to the **.retries** queue and scheduled for retry. If the SLR policy output is that it needs to be retried then the message is forwarded to the **.retries** queue.

#### NServiceBus v4.x

The SLR policy is only applied on the distributor for both *NumberOfRetries* and *TimeIncrease* settings.

The distributor has a **.retries** queue where a message is forwarded to in case of an error. Then the distributor processes this message, when the retry limit has been reached the message will be forwarded to the error queue or else scheduled for retry by the distributor.

#### NServiceBus v3.x

The SLR policy is applied *only* on the workers for both *TimeIncrease* and *NumberOfRetries* settings. If a SLR configuration is available on the distributor then these settings are ignored.

When an error occurs the worker schedules the retry according to the SLR TimeIncrease setting and when the corresponding timeout is triggered the message is forwarded to the incoming queue of the distributor which will then forward the message to an available worker.

Comment: Thanks Ramon for your time and documenting it.

Answer (score 0):

This will result in the first SLR starting after 5 minutes... was that your intent?

I testted this on the code sample from [the Particular docs whebsite](http://docs.particular.net/samples/errorhandling/#Nuget-v4_x)

Does this work for you?

Comment: Added the Scenario. When the worker enlists with Distributor, it does not respects its second level retries, it goes to distributor and the SLR is respected in Distributor Configuration.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, all retry scenarios will be dealt with by the distributor. Any failures when a worker is handling a message get propagated back up to the distributor, which will perform FLRs and SLRs, before moving the message on to the configured error queue.

Comment: See Ramon's answer above